# VueX: populating associations between modules

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to build my store as closely to a REST API as possible. Now I load 2 modules from the API directly into the sotre, where one of them can be referenced in the other one.

**For example:**

Each **Car** in my **Car** module has an **Engine** attribute which is a number. That number refers to the ID of an **Engine** which I also have in another store module.

Now when accessing the **Cars** getter I want a convenient way to merge each **Engine** into the associated **Car**, so that my components don't have to do that.

Now of course I could just get both getters and write some computed property like so:

```
carWithEngine () {
  return this.cars.map(c => ({
    ...c,
    engine: this.engines.find(e => e.id === c.engine)
  }))
}
```

I could even outsource this into a mixin to make it reusable but it'll still only work for cars and engines.

I'm looking for a more generic way, where I could just give the store two getters and the attributes it's supposed to merge, **without losing the reactiveness**.

Comment: an example would probably help https://codesandbox.io/s/vue

Comment: @A.Lau it's a generic question with a generic example. I got my code working with the example provided, I just want a more reusable way.

Comment: Can you not make a compound getter from the car getter and engine getter? Import store with `import { store } from '../store'` and use it to construct a 'higher order getter' with the same logic as the computed property.

Comment: @RichardMatsen is that a common practice? Doesn't sound too bad.

Comment: Well, not commonly shown in tutorials but I just found one that comes close [cartTotalPrice](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/examples/shopping-cart/store/modules/cart.js)

Comment: I can say that using store from within a store module works, as I do `store.commit` within a module that tracks resource loading.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try this out as my first approach.

Comment: The `cartTotalPrice` is a little bit different, since it's 'child' getter is within the the same module - but worth trying across multiple modules with the import.

Comment: The best composition I was able to achieve was by adding yet another getter as a second parameter to the compound getter. This way I was able to write a single populating compound getter while passing in any previous filtering getter. Overall I'm happy with this result, thanks @RichardMatsen
The only annoying thing was that I needed to import the state from each module as well and pass it to the getter, as I'm using strictly namespaced modules.